# HttpClient Intermittent Page Not Found

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I use the following code and run the method multiple times, a few times I get a response in GZIP which is what I expect and a few other times I get a response that is completely different(non GZIP page not found). However if I download the same URL multiple times using Mozilla or IE I consistently get the same GZIP response.

Is this an error with the server I am trying to reach to, or do I need to set any parameters to get a consistent response ?

The URL I am trying to download [is the following](http://www.walmart.com/navigation6.xml.gz), can you please let me know ?

```
public static byte[] dowloadURL(URL urlToDownload) {

    InputStream iStream = null;
    byte[] urlBytes = null;

    try {

        //HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        org.apache.http.client.
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();


        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlToDownload.toString());

        HttpResponse response  = httpClient.execute(httpget);

        iStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

        urlBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(iStream);
        String responseString = new String(urlBytes);
        System.out.println(" >>> The response  string for " +urlToDownload.toString()+  " is "   +responseString);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.printf("Failed while reading bytes from %s: %s",
                urlToDownload.toExternalForm(), e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Perform any other exception handling that's appropriate.
    } finally {
        if (iStream != null) {
            try {
                iStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return urlBytes;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace?

Comment: Maybe there is some throttling on the server which prevents multiple requests from the same source in a short period of time. It's possible that your Java code does this quickly enough to trigger the throttle, whilst when you do it manually in the browser, it's not as fast so the throttle isn't triggered.